# Excel, Create column stating if row is equal to certain values

Tags: excel

There is an extract of my table below,

| ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 252708 | Phone | Phone | Phone | Phone | Phone | Phone |  |  |
| 252252 | Phone |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 253022 | Phone |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 253080 | Phone | Phone | Phone | Email | Phone |  |  |  |
| 253228 | Phone | Phone | Phone | Phone | Phone |  |  |  |
| 253282 | Phone |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 256200 | Phone |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 256279 | Phone | Phone | Email |  |  |  |  |  |
| 256703 | Phone |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 236457 | Email |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 257560 | Phone | Phone | Phone | Email | Phone | Phone | Phone | Phone |

I want to create an additional column that states whether it's row is made up of **Just Phone**, **Phone and Email**, or **Just Email**. To look like the below,

| Status |
| --- |
| Just Phone |
| Just Phone |
| Just Phone |
| Phone and Email |
| Just Phone |
| Just Phone |
| Just Phone |
| Phone and Email |
| Just Phone |
| Just Email |
| Phone and Email |

I've tried lots of variations of the **if** function, but my main issues is the blanks in some of the rows.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" and ",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(B2:I2)))
```

If your version of excel supports `LAMBDA()` function then can try below formula for one go.

```
=BYROW(B2:I12,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" and ",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(x)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Dada, if the word is "Just " is needed, then `=LET(x,TEXTJOIN(" and ",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(B2:I2))),
BYROW(x,LAMBDA(a,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" and ",a)),a,"Just "&a))))`

Comment: Good suggestion. Also we can count unique values then, if count is greater than 1 then no need `Just` word. If count is `1` then add `Just` word.

Comment: Dada please update with the formula you have mentioned, so it helps others as well

Comment: Non array approach `=LET(x,COUNTA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:I2,B2:I2<>"")))),y,TEXTJOIN(" and ",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(B2:I2))),IF(x>1,y,"Just " &y))`

Comment: Dynamic array approach `=LET(x,COUNTA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:I2,B2:I2<>"")))),y,BYROW(B2:I12,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" and ",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(a))))),IF(x>1,y,"Just " &y))`.

Comment: Super Dada =) let me apply